# Low-pass filter in SPICE

Tags: spice, analog-filter

I have a simple question about a low-pass filter. Without a load I have a resonance effect.

[image: Low pass filter]

/!\ I forgot to delete a modification on the previous screenshot the 0.5 Ohms resistor after V1 that's my bad...

With a load of 1 Ω the result is what I expect:

[image: With a load of 1 Ω]

And with 100 kΩ:

[image: With a load of 100 kΩ]

Load is a motor, [Faulhaber 2342S024CR](https://www.faulhaber.com/fileadmin/Import/Media/EN_2342_CR_DFF.pdf), driven by 28V PWM. And is not represented on the simulation.

Thanks you guys for the informations and your time. Next time I will try to be clearer I'm really sorry for the mistakes.

Comment: You haven’t asked a question.

Comment: Node numbers mean nothing here.

Comment: What are you measuring ? Voltage accross R1 ? Or one R1 node ...

Comment: Oh excuse me I measure the output between R1.
And my question is why there is a gain when the output is an "open circuit" and not when the load is very low.

Comment: What doudou whant to Know ? What is your question ?

Comment: You must calculate it ... It is a second order system (C1 and C2 do nothing). Can you do it?

Comment: Well I can try to see how to calculate it. But actualy, I'm using LTspice because I'm too bad at math.
About C1 & C2 is it possible that it filter some noise that come from the supply side ?
This is a PWM controlled motor, the filter is there to reduce the EMI from the brushes.

Comment: You say "between R1", but the screenshot shows one node to ground, surely it should be `V(n002,n003)` or something like that? As for response, what are you doing with it? You say motor; what type is it, and what is it driven by? What amount of filtering do you require, or for what purpose -- EMC regulations? What does the surrounding equipment look like? (EMC depends on everything between the source and the antenna picking it up. Potentially the whole system is in question!)

Comment: I edited the schematic Screenshot to show my measurement node.
The motor is a Faulhaber 2342S024CR drived by a +28V PWM.
Some people made this filter card and I'm investigating on the purpose and efficiency of it. I'm realy noob on LTspice and filtering.

Comment: Something is screwy. With a 0.5ohm -> 1.0ohm divider you should get a passband gain of something around -3.5dB. Not 0dB.

Comment: Your schematic will not produce that response. I see you updated your schematic but, it now is at odds with the graphical results as per what SteKulov says.

Comment: I'm realy sorry the 0.5Ohms isn't supposed to be there I forgot to delete this modification when I updated the screenshot.

Answer (score 2):

If the load is absent the high output voltage comes from the resonance of the inductors and capacitors in your circuit. You can perhaps use a time-domain SPICE simulation to see how the signal in that case will swing up after it is started.

If the load is present (and has a low resistor value) then you are to some extent shorting the output signal. That is especially imprtant around the resonance frequency because there the output impedance is high, so the load has much influence.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working simulation of your circuit for loads of 1Ω, 5Ω and almost open-circuit. I've moved the ground to the output side so that it's not necessary to subtract two voltages.

You'll notice that the behaviour near resonance appears different (peaking but no notch) and the passband gain is correct with the heavy load.

[image]

Comment: Hi, "I've moved the ground to the output side so that it's not necessary to subtract two voltages." what do you mean by substract I just probed the positiv side of R1. 
What do you mean by passband gain is correct, this filter is supposed to be a lowpass filter ?.. :)

Comment: I am taking the output voltage as the voltage across your R1, not the voltage from top of R1 to the (-) of the source voltage. That's a fundamental difference.  It's how I would expect a common mode filter to work. As to the second question, raised in a comment above, you have (well, 'had', you edited it out, which is rather bad etiquette because it invalidates answers people have spent time composing) a series resistance of 0.5Ω and a load of 1Ω so 0dB is wrong.